# Socket.io stopped working after updating android sdk to 28

Tags: android, sockets, ionic-framework, socket.io

I am building an Android application which is using socket.io.
I have updated it to use the sdk 28. It works fine on browser but not in the real device or emulator.

The AndroidManifest.xml file contains the following:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" 
android:supportsRtl="true" 
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
```

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">mysocketdomain.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

There is no way to downgrade the sdk since Google is not accepting apps using sdk below 28.

What the heck is goin on? I've read some issues related to this and no solution has worked at all...

Also, it is not a problem with the socket not any other code, since when I load the app via browser it connects immediately to the socket and I've tested socket sending messages, the browser is receiving. The real device, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake of mine. Instead of false, it should be true, as following. The website should also be a domain and not an IP, making these changes, the socket in the device is working again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">mysocketdomain.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```